# Merging and Centering Cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I recently set out to write a simple macro the merge/unmerge cells with a keyboard shortcut.

The macro is working currently with the following code:

```
If Selection.MergeCells = True Then
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
ElseIf Selection.MergeCells = False Then
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
Selection.Merge
End If
```

This works perfectly well, but I originally had a much simpler sub that didn't work.  It was:

```
If Selection.MergeCells = False Then Selection.Merge
If Selection.MergeCells = True Then Selection.UnMerge
```

This two-line version only worked to merge cells, not to unmerge them.  Does anyone know why this was happening?

Thanks.

-Sean

Comment: Those 2 lines works perfectly for me.  Check the following:  
1) Is one line immediately followed by the other? (unmerged something and immediately merge it)
2) Is your selection correct?
3) Is there contents in the cells that's merging / unmerging prevents it from doing so? (i.e. you have "on error resume next" somewhere)

Comment: I just reverted to the 2-line version, and it didn't work at all.  I'm not sure exactly what is/was going on.  Glad to know that I'm not totally off base with my original idea though.  Just to add: I was merging cells, selecting a different cell, then selecting the merged cells and trying to unmerge them.  Also, the cells never had any content in them.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an **ELSE**

```
Sub qwerty()
    If Selection.MergeCells = False Then
        Selection.Merge
    Else
        Selection.UnMerge
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this out and it works perfectly.  Any idea why the ELSE is needed though?  I mean, I know that it makes the unmerge function default, but if one condition or the other is true, then the two if statements should work, no?

Comment: In  the original code, if the first statement works, then second statement will un-do it.